# Clone disk to slightly smaller SSD

Tags: linux, clone

I am using Linux (Fedora 21) and have a 500GB SSHD that shows some failure errors. I bought a new SSD disk of 480GB and I want to clone the SSHD to the SSD. There is more than enough free space, so the slightly smaller disk should be no problem. I tried to use CloneZilla for this, but it bails out complaining the target disk is too small.

My partition layout is as follows:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf215ba27

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1              63     80324     80262  39.2M de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2  *        81920  32935935  32854016  15.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        32935936 434964442 402028507 191.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       434964480 976773167 541808688 258.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       434966528 435990527   1024000   500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       435992576 976773119 540780544 257.9G 8e Linux LVM
```

And these are the mounted file systems:

```
[bf@laptop-bf ~]$ df
Filesystem                        1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                            4027292         0   4027292   0% /dev
tmpfs                               4039452       220   4039232   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               4039452      1832   4037620   1% /run
tmpfs                               4039452         0   4039452   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-root  51475068  13636828  35200416  28% /
tmpfs                               4039452        40   4039412   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3                         201014248     93952 200920296   1% /mnt/windows7
/dev/sda5                            487652    174469    283487  39% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora_localhost-home 206394032 172686096  23200672  89% /home
tmpfs                                807892        12    807880   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                807892        28    807864   1% /run/user/1000
```

What tool could I use to clone my disk?

Comment: a) `rsync -X ...` b) shrink your partition first with gparted then copy

Comment: Under no circumstances move a partition with errors in it. This will not recover any bad sectors, but it will move good sectors to bad ones, effectively doubling the lost data.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious partition to shrink is `/dev/sda3` (Win7). If this has a running W7 on it, it is safest to shrink from within that. Since it has so much unused space, I would shrink by more than 20GB, so that subsequently more space can be made available in the nearly full Linux partition.

Then use Linux for the copying. It will be better to use a LiveCD, to stop any disc changes during the copy. I recommend Ubuntu live, which has the excellent `gparted` on it.

When there are disc errors, I use `dd conv=noerrror,sync ...`, with the default 512-byte buffer, which is slow, but copies the maximum number of good sectors.

I would copy the whole disc with `dd`, which will error after copying all the sectors it can fit on to the SSD. If the target is `/dev/sdb`, then use:

```
dd  conv=noerrror,sync if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

You can use `count=435992576` to stop the copy before `/dev/sda6`, which will be written in the next stage.

If you use `gparted` you can now easily delete the extended partition on the target drive and copy the extended partition from the old drive into the free space on the new drive, then expand both the extended and the LVM partition to use the rest of the space on the new drive.

You can do this copy with `dd skip=... seek=... ...`, but you need to make sure of the offsets, whereas `gparted` does all the arithmetic for you.

The important thing is not to do anything on the old drive until you have created a successful, bootable copy on the new drive, where all the partitions pass a disc check (`fsck` or `chkdsk.exe`)

This is not an easy solution, but by taking a very conservative approach it maximises the data recovered to the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers point to valid open-source solutions, you can shrink partitions on the source disk (with gparted) and clone the disk on the destination disk using the "dd" command or "clonezilla".

But, I like to propose one non-open alternative solution.

**EaseUS Backup Free**, is a very good proprietary software for Microsoft Windows that also performs disc-clone with automatic on-the-fly shrink. This is ideal for HD->SSD migration.

In case you need to execute EaseUS on another Linux-only machine, with the EaseUS Backup Free software you can also create a **bootable WinPE DVD/USB drive**.
You can **create the bootable emergency disk** directly from EasyUS, **from menu "Tools" > "Create Emergency Disk"**, and then select the WinPE option (it is the choice that provides more features).

While booting with the EaseUS Emergency Disc you execute a full-fledged EaseUS Backup Free instance, and you can perform all the disc-clone operations you need.
The EasyUS graphical interface is quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

Using gparted shrink the disk down below the size of the target disk. Then when using clonezilla I believe there is an option to expand the partitions as it copies them.

That said you may also run into issues with the bad sectors. If you do you may have to use the rescue flag when copying everything over or clonezilla will quit on the first error. It has been a while since I did this so i am not sure where it is but if you read the options as you go it should be obvious.

Comment: I try that now, but the last partition on my disk is a LVM and there is no free space to shrink that partition.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - Could you elaborate your question to add a partition layout, indicating which can be shrunk by 20GB?

Comment: @AFH I updated my question. Both the Windows7 and the home dir could be shrunk